# How to destroy and clear string variable contents from memory?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, security, memory-management

What is a **secure way to remove all traces of an string variable from memory**? 
I already know about usage of `SecureString` class but sometimes it's required to import or process data from external sources and most of them are working with strings; here is an example:

```vb
    Dim decrypted_data() As Byte = Decrypt(...)
    Dim temp As String = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted_data)
    Dim sec As SecureString = GetSecureString(temp)
    ' Now I should remove temp contents from memory
```

Or a better solution in my example would be the Idea to directly writing encrypted data to SecureString but I don't have any idea how could it be possible.

Comment: You ask for a "secure" solution without saying what attack the solution must be secure against. Who is attacking, what are they attacking, and why is shredding memory a mitigation?

Comment: @EricLippert Imagine someone has access to my application. There are some hack tools which can show application strings in a list. So I don't prefer to see my application `decrypted_data` in that list. I want to clear all traces of sensitive information after converting them to a more secure type like `SecureString` or `encrypted_bytes_of_data`.

Comment: The person who is running those tools, are they a *user* of your application? Or are they a person *attacking* the user of your application? If you are attempting to protect the application from your own users then I submit to you that your user trust model is broken; the user is the person who must trust *your software*, not vice versa! Your software is the servant of the user, not its master. If the attacker is attacking the user then I submit that the attacker must already have admin access to the user's machine, and the user has already lost.

Comment: I note that my analysis in the previous comment contains an important - deliberate - error. Do you see it? The presumption that an attacker with admin access is an automatic loss for the user, and therefore mitigations against the given attack are useless, is not warranted. For example, admins never need to have the plain text of a user password, and it is therefore sensible to shred passwords so that even a hostile admin cannot get the plain text easily. (The hostile admin could of course install a key logger, but that then relies upon the user typing the password.)

Comment: That said, it is still the case that attacks where the attacker is presumed to already own the system, these are not generally interesting attacks to protect against. It's better to focus efforts on preventing an attacker from escalating privilege to admin in the first place.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree, but my problem is about application cracks because my country is not including any software legal copyright protections. I send my application trail version to everyone and I don't know who is real user or hacker. A hacker may even purchase a key from me to break my application protections and I have encrypted strings which contains sensitive data such install date, license expire time, username, key,... and it's a big risk for me to have traces of such information remained on application even in memory.

Comment: Microsoft made a terrible error calling this class “SecureString”; people seem to believe the implication that putting sensitive in memory is inherently insecure and that encrypting it will ultimately do anything much against an attacker who is already administrator. SecureString is a useful mitigation in a limited set of circumstances; otherwise trying to keep sensitive data out of memory, especially for external toosl, is a complete waste of your time. If you intend to solve the Copy Protection Problem then, well... bigger cleverer companies than you have been trying for decades and failed.

Comment: @bobince I understand your vision and I agree that there is no full trustworthy security solution but my key is working per computers cpu unique ID. So When the user request a key my key generator is generating key based on user `HardwareID` so this protects hackers to reproduce unlocked state of my application by replacing unlocked key files. They need to know my calculations to reproduce keys for other computers. The thing I should focus is to protect hackers reproduce encryption calculations and accessing my application keys used to produce unlocked key.

Comment: @bobince I've also not whole trust `SecureString` class and parts of my unlocker key data are placed in some custom encryption class which encrypts and holds bytes of data using standard encryption algorithms plus holding encrypted data in ProtectedMemory area and current thread scope while reading/writing them from/to application memory. So the most dangerous threat which remains is temporary memory objects as strings which should be cleared as well.

Comment: Just move your calculation algorithm in the web service.

Comment: @Fabio Very good idea which I never think before and can be used for extra layer of security, but actually I insist to hold at least parts of calculations / key-data in client application and clearing string traces would not be something hard to stop me to do so,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I have done it this way:

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub ZeroFree(ByRef str As String)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
        Return
    End If
    If String.IsInterned(str) IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Throw New Exception("Interned strings are not supported!")
        Return
    End If
    Dim gch As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject, str.Length * 2 - 1)
    gch.Free()
    str = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub ZeroMemory(ByVal location As IntPtr, ByVal size As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To size
        Marshal.WriteByte(IntPtr.Add(location, i), 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

*From comments:*

**NOTE:** This is the best solution I could find to cross over this issue but Its not a generic or 100% solution and it will not work in special situations for example it not clear copy of same string if it was automatically copied previously by garbage collector.
Greater Ideas, or helpful recommendations are always welcome!

Comment: This of course won't work.  It's *entirely* possible, even plausible, that the data from this string will still exist and be accessible after calling this method.  When Eric said that you'd already lost, he didn't say it lightly.

Comment: Oh, and if you ever use this method on an interned string, you're completely hosing the intern pool, which is very bad.

Comment: @Servy No I have tested and tried to retrieve the string from memory address and it was cleared as expected. How you rate down without testing and having a proof?!

Comment: @Servy I think String.IsInterned() is the method to protect that happen.

Comment: The fact that you couldn't do it doesn't make it impossible.  That string is very plausably going to exist in any number of places.  The GC is likely to have copied it some number of times, if there have been any GC collections, and it's not going to bother to clear out those old copies when it's done with them, etc.

Comment: @Servy I'm searching for a solution to replcace old copies as well, but this is better than doing nothing about issue. I'll appreciate if you have any better idea. But until I find a better solution I know to Zero Importatnt string immediately after using them and before executing more codes which may cause GC to collect.

Comment: A false sense of security *isn't* better than nothing.  Claiming a solution as doing something that it doesn't do, and therefore claiming to be protected from something that you're not actually protecting yourself from is quite likely to be worse than *knowing* that you aren't protected from that thing.

Comment: @Servy But *its not* exactly false sense of security as you say. Its doing the job as expected, but what you are talking about is happening by chance because you say IF garbage collects and IF not means that 100% will happen.

Comment: @Servy And you told me it will not work at all so you're chatting about something you don't have enough expertise!

Comment: You're claiming that this clears that string's data from memory.  That claim is false.  It's possible that this *might* do that, some of the time, but not reliably, and worse you won't even have any way of knowing whether or not you have a *critical security leak* when you do have one.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you about lacks but until I found a better solution, I'll use this. I asked you a better idea and you say *NOTHING*. So for someone who cares about security risks, if not possible to stop attacks, he prefer to *reduce* them, so for sure he'll prefer to do *something* rather than *nothing*.

Comment: No, I'm not going to say nothing when you're going to take a completely insecure and fallible solution and claim that it completely solves this problem, because it doesn't.  You may not care if you trick others into thinking that they've solved a problem when they have in fact done no such thing, but I don't consider that acceptable.

Comment: @Servy So what's your idea?! I'll accept your answer if you find a better or even similar solution.

Comment: The problem is impossible.  But it's better to know that it's impossible than to drink the snake oil and be under the false impression that you have a miracle cure to the impossible problem.

Comment: I don't agree! Nothing stops a real man to reach the goal! even if the bridge is broken, I'll *CREATE* my own! *Nothing* is not accepted by me. Give me better idea and you're accepted.

Comment: If you don't agree that the solution is impossible then why don't you prove that it *is* possible.  So far you've nether provided an *actual* solution (merely asserted that a non-solution is a solution), not even demonstrated that it would be theoretically possible.  The burden of proof is on you to back up such a claim.

Comment: @Servy I have done my part and I can prove it works by tests. You didn't prooved what you talk about! You even judged and rated down before tesing results! I can guess what kind of human you are. If you know something, that's not because you read books or searched! It's because they **ARE** in books by experiments to be read. There is nothing which mean *IMPOSSIBLE* with programming. I'm experiencing problem and you insist to be stopped at current knowledge!

Comment: @Raymon: Take a look at the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for something impossible to solve in general.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi Long story. I have read glancing and updated the code to throw exception were intern strings are not supported, If I understood correct.

Comment: @Raymon: Maybe you misunderstood my last comment: it was a reply to your previous statement "_There is nothing which mean IMPOSSIBLE with programming_". Actually there is, since no algorithm exists that could solve the halting problem in general.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi If it was 100% impossible, then how programs are working now?